# how to identify if MPI process belongs to a given Communicator

Tags: mpi

I have create A communicator using the construct `MPI_Comm_split()`, And then I want to try some send/receive communication both at **MPI_Comm_World** level and at the new-communicators level. Two communicators are created (one with even-process rank the other with odd-rank).

**NOTE:** I need to try communication only inside the new communicator that contains even-process-ranks (though the rank of the processes is not the original one, I am still concerned with what those process have in their memory space)

My code is as follows,

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include "mpi.h"
    int main(int arg, char **argv){
    int rank,newrank,newrank2;
    int size, newSize,newSize2;
    int data;
    int recv;
    MPI_Comm newComm, newComm2;
    MPI_Status status, newStatus;
    MPI_Init(&arg,&argv);

    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);    
    //sample data
    data = rank * 100 + 1;

    printf("my rank in the WORLD is: %d\n", rank);
    fflush(stdout); 

    if(rank%2==0){
    MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD,0,rank,&newComm);
    MPI_Comm_rank(newComm,&newrank);
    MPI_Comm_size(newComm,&newSize);    
    printf("my rank in the newComm1 is : %d\n", newrank);
    }else{      
            MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD,1,rank,&newComm2);
            MPI_Comm_rank(newComm2,&newrank2);
            MPI_Comm_size(newComm2,&newSize2);        
    printf("my rank in the newComm2 is : %d\n", newrank2);
    }

    //Now try some communication at the newCommunicator and at the WORLD level
    if(rank == 0){
    //sending to process 1 wrt WOLD_Comm
    MPI_Send(&data,1,MPI_INT,1,99,MPI_COMM_WORLD);      
    }
    if(rank==1){
    //Receive from process at WORLD_Comm level. 
    MPI_Recv(&recv,1,MPI_INT,0,99,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
    printf("Received at WORLD Level : %d \n\n",recv);
    }
    if(newSize > 2){
    if(newrank == 2){
        //send to process 1 wrt the newComm
        MPI_Send(&data,1,MPI_INT,1,0,newComm);
    }
    if(newrank==1){
        //Receive from process at newComm level.
        MPI_Recv(&recv,1,MPI_INT,2,0,newComm,&status);
        printf("Received at newComm Level : %d \n\n",recv);
    }
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
    }
```

The error happens when the I try to send/receive data inside `new Communicator`. The error makes sense because process that do not belong to the new communicator (odd-rank processes) can not use the new communicator handle (newComm).

So my question is how can I check if a given process belongs to the new communicator or not.
So that I can put this guard before doing any communication.

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd revisit the code doing `MPI_Comm_split`.  From what I can tell, you don't need two separate variables `newComm` and `newComm2`.  When you call `MPI_Comm_split`, you can think of multiple communicators being created globally: one for each value of `color`.  But each process calling `MPI_Comm_split` only gets a reference to one communicator - the one it belongs to.

The `if` statement with `MPI_Comm_split` can be replaced by

```
MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD, (rank % 2 == 0), rank, &newComm);
MPI_Comm_rank(newComm, &newrank);
MPI_Comm_size(newComm, &newSize);
```

Two communicators are created, but `newComm` refers to a different communicator in different processes.

If the odd-numbered processes don't need to communicate at all, you can make them supply `MPI_UNDEFINED` for `color`.  This will make them get a value of `MPI_COMM_NULL` for `newComm`:

```
MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD, (rank % 2) ? MPI_UNDEFINED : 0, rank, &newComm);
```

Then your code can check if `(newcomm == MPI_COMM_NULL)`.

Comment: hey Greg Inozemtsev, thank you very much!
just one question though: what if I still need communication of odd-numbered processes but not now, they will be used later in the code. Now, having that in mind when I check if(rank==0), two processes able to pass this if statement one from even-numbered group and the other from odd-numbered group. which is what I don't want and that is why I try to use two separate handles. 
Is there any other way please??

Comment: That's what the first snippet does.  We use `(rank % 2 == 0)` for the color argument.  Which means that on even-numbered processes, `color == 1`, and on odd-numbered processes `color == 0`.  After `MPI_Comm_split` returns, we have 3 communicators: the original `MPI_COMM_WORLD`, and a communicator for each `color`.  On even-numbered ranks, `newComm` refers to the communicator where callers supplied `color == 1` (so, the even ranks).  On odd-numbered ranks, `newComm` is the communicator with processes that had `color == 0` (the odd ranks).  And `MPI_COMM_WORLD` still contains all processes.